# Kendo UI grid selectable option in IE7

Tags: jquery, frameworks, grid, kendo-ui

I've created a grid using Kendo UI.

My goal is to not show any highlighting when I hover (or mouse-over) each line in the grid.
So far this is working for me in IE8, IE9, Firefox, but not IE7.

Thank you

Here is the code for my grid:

```
$("#Summary").kendoGrid({
    navigatable : true,
    scrollable : false,
    filterable : isFilterable,
    sortable : true,
    resizable : true,
    previousNext:false,
    pageable : {

        refresh : false,
        input : false,
        numeric : true,
        buttonCount:4,
        pageSizes : ddResultsPerPage
    },
    rowTemplate : summaryRowtemplate,
    altRowTemplate : summaryAltRowtemplate,
    dataBound : formatSummaryRow,
    columns : summaryColumns
});
```

Comment: Could you post the code of your row-templates including their CSS? In the online demos of the kendoGrid (http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/editing.html), none of the samples have a hover state for the rows. Where does that hover-state come from in your site?

Comment: The issue is with IE.  I had to change the css settings, instead of "transparent", I had to use "none".  Now, my grid is working as it should.